# Null Reference while calling ADAL AcquireTokenAsync in a Xamarin Forms iOS App

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, adal

Using ADAL to authenticate a Xamarin iOS App. All good during initial login but when signing out and signing back again (e.g. redirecting to login when AccessToken expires after 90 days), the App Crashes with the following

```
Unhandled managed exception:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object (System.NullReferenceException)
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform.DidAppear () [0x0000d] in :0
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PlatformRenderer.ViewDidAppear (Boolean animated) [0x00006] in :0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2077/d8e9592a/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:74
at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0001c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2077/d8e9592a/source/maccore/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:57
at MyAwesomeApp.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x0000c] in d:\Working\City.Australia\MyAwesomeApp\Main\MyAwesomeApp\MyAwesomeApp\MyAwesomeApp.iOS\Main.c
s:18
```

Source Code

```
var view = appDelegate.RootViewController;
appDelegate.MakeKeyAndVisible();
AdalInitializer.Initialize();
var azureSettings = AzureSettings.GetSettings();
AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(azureSettings.AdAuthority);
```

The next line is where it fails

```
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(azureSettings.AdResource,
azureSettings.AdClientId,
new Uri(azureSettings.AdRedirect),
new AuthorizationParameters(view),
UserIdentifier.AnyUser,
string.Format(“domain_hint={0}”, azureSettings.AdDomainHint));
```

Like I mentioned, first time signing in is good, but signing out and signing again results in Null reference exception in the ***AcquireTokenAsync*** call. If anyone had experienced this issue or familiar with this, please let me know.

The issue is not with the ADAL library call but to do with the UIViewController. Have tried to make it thread safe and tested with task to delay but once it gets to ***AcquireTokenAsync*** App crashes with null reference exception

Cannot get a sample app immediately but will try to get one if there is not much success with this.

Xamarin Forms: 1.4

ADAL (Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory) : 3.1.0.0

Any suggestions / help much appreciated.

Regards

Vinod Srinivasan

Comment: Digging deeper into the issue, it could possibly because of a bug in older versions of XF.Calling the _MainPage_ more than once dynamically seem to be an issue for many. Need to upgrade to the latest version to see if this still occurs. Could be More info [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37307/null-reference-exception-when-setting-new-app-mainpage)

Comment: Any update? I am having similar issue.

Comment: Hi @ManishJain , Hi did not get to update the XF since I moved companies and was nt part of the project. Apologies for not being able to help you. Which version of XF are you using ? Try updating your XF and ADAL libraries (not sure if there is any update to this) to the latest version to see if this problem is resolved.